# Description (or better Notes) property of exchange group won't be shown through Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When you create within a Microsoft tenant an exchange only group like a distribution group or a mail-enabled security group it is possible to set through the exchange admin center the description property of such a group (which is named in exchange internally "Notes").

If this property is set to an arbitrary value and afterwards read this group through the Graph API, the property description is always `null`.

Exists any possibility to read this Notes/Description field from an exchange group through the Graph API, cause other things like name or members can be retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out.

Description being null seems to be a product bug. We have raised an issue on this internally. Unfortunately, we do not have an ETA yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Are they any possibilities to get an update on this issue? Should I open up a support ticket on Azure, feedback portal or tech community or will you post an update here?

Comment: I will post an update here, But we do not have any ETA yet on this.

Comment: This has been fixed now.

Comment: Tested it within my tenant, but neither Azure Portal nor Graph Explorer showing the filled notes field within the description property. Probably we have to wait some time till it is GA maybe.

Comment: Another day, another test. Unfortunately still no luck. Exchange shows notes, but Azure Portal and Graph Explorer return `null` in description.

Comment: Could you share details of the API call being made including  Client request-id and timestamp.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but I don't think, the comment area of an SO answer is the right place to do so. Any other possibility to contact you? (By the way, it still returns null)